# grep output "begin" option

Tags: dhcp, grep

Is there an option to get the output from the grep but that output needs to start with the word that I am searching for? This is really hard to explain so let me give an example here:

When you want to search for something in Cisco running configuration I would use the following command:

show running-configuration | b 10.0.1.202 - The output would start right where the 10.0.1.202 was mentioned the first time.

For example I have a very long file of dhcp.leases on my CentOS, but how can I grep | b 10.0.1.202 so that my output starts where the 10.0.1.202 was first time found, and the rest of the output is listed after that?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grep for the address but show an infinite amount of context lines (using `-A` for "lines after", similarly `-B` "lines before", `-C` "lines surrounding"):

```
cat dhcp.leases | grep -A9999999 '10\.0\.1\.202'
```

Though in your case you *probably* just want 10-20 lines, not the whole thing, so you should specify the desired amount after `-A`.

I usually use awk for cropping out specific ranges (e.g. from regex 1 to regex 2):

```
cat dhcp.leases | awk '/10\.0\.1\.202/ {found=1} found {print}'
cat dhcp.leases | awk '/10\.0\.1\.202/{f=1}f'

cat somefile | awk '/^Begin:/{ok=1} ok{print} /^End:/{ok=0}'
```

Comment: Thank you! I used "grep -A20" and that did the job just fine! I am not familiar with the awk, but I will give it a try.